# How to mail merge into more that one specific merge field on the same document

Tags: mailmerge, aspose

Good Day

I want to apply mail merge to a document which have 4 name, surname and birthday fields.
The reason why I did this is to save paper.
How can I use a loop to print each merge field with a different row in the data source.

I'm using Aspose.Words by the way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Microsoft Word you could use Rules...Next Record and the end of a cell or a row. adding this hidden field at the end of a table cell or row will get the data from the next record on the same page, saving you paper ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by executing "Mail Merge with Regions" functionality of Aspose.Words. Please refer to the following articles:

- [Mail Merge with Regions Explained](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Mail+Merge+with+Regions+Explained)
- [How to Execute Mail Merge with Regions](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Execute+Mail+Merge+with+Regions)

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.